# How to handle 100 Mbps input stream when my program can process data only at 1 Mbps rate

Tags: c++, performance, caching

I am working on a project where we can have input data stream with 100 Mbps.

My program can be used overnight for capturing these data and thus will generate huge data file. My program logic which interpret these data is complex and can process only 1 Mb data per second.

We also dump the bytes to some log file after getting processed. We do not want to loose any incoming data and at the same time want my program to work in real time.So; we are maintaining a circular buffer which acts like a cache.

Right now only way to save incoming data from getting lost is to increase size of this buffer.

Please suggest better way to do this and also what are the alternate way of caching I can try?

Comment: I presume you mean 100 Mbps (100 megabits per second) not 100 mbps (100 millibits per second) ?

Comment: @Paul yes it is 100 megabits per second.I have corrected the question.

Answer (score 3):

Stream the input to a file. Really, there is no other choice. It comes in faster than you can process it.

You could create one file per second of input data. That way you can directly start processing old files while new files are being streamed on the disk.

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık, that would make sense. The OP needs to stream to disk anyway because of the high data volume.

Comment: I think file will slow down the performance.So; I will like to handle it using some caching. I know if we are consistently getting data on the same speed the incoming data will be lost. But there is possibility that incoming data speed will not be consistently at this high spped.

Comment: when the phase-change memory is released, will be no problem i think